# Sort sting with numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Hi can someone help me sort string with numbers in java script.

I want to sort these options using jquery according to their distance `(9 km)`.

```
    <select >
        <option >Point a (9 km)</option>
        <option >Point b (10 km)</option>
        <option >Point c (2 km)</option>
    </select>
```

Basically I just want to sort string that has some numbers in them.Another example.

```
input:
var arr = ['A (9 km)','B (10 km)','C (2 km)']

output:
C (2 km)
A (9 km)
B (10 km)
```

You got the point.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you figured out how to get the number from the text yet? If not; start there with your research efforts

Comment: I know how to extract those text man.
Just want to sort those extracted strings.

Comment: Ok. But you haven't shown any attempt to parse those strings so it appears you are asking others to code every bit of this for you. At least showing that you have researched some of the basics will help. SO isn't a free code writing service and basic research is expected

Comment: he means to pull the actual number from each string in the array. This is going to be a two step process. First extract only the number from the existing string then sort by those extracted numbers.

Comment: you'll need to remove those option elements from their parent and recreate them.

Comment: @Typo Not really, can sort them as elements also

Comment: @charlietfl not really or also?

Comment: They don't need to be recreated

Comment: you're right about that, they dont need anything...

Comment: @charlietfl :-P

Comment: awww..come on man, it has being a long time since I pick a fight in SO

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after ?

```js
const distances = ['A (9 km)','B (10 km)','C (2 km)']; 
const sorted = distances
   .map((x,i)=>[parseInt(x.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''),10),i])
   .sort((a,b)=>a[0]-b[0])
   .map(x=>distances[x[1]]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort any array in-place using [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

The meat of the operation is extracting the number from the string, which I assume you can do already based on another comment. Let's assume your function that can do this `pointToNumber(pointStr)`

For anyone else coming to this question later, `Number.parseInt(str.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10)` would probably accomplish it if you know that your string will only have a single number in it.

That said, here is how you can sort such an array:

```js
const arr = ['A (9 km)','B (10 km)','C (2 km)']
arr
    .map(point => [pointToNumber(point), point])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => {
        return a - b;
    })
    .map(([, point]) => point);
```

The real magic here is in `a - b`. This is because a sorting comparator function can return either `0`, `-1` (or any negative number), or `1` (or any positive number).

As mentioned in the linked msdn, returning a negative number causes `a` to be sorted into an index lower than `b`, and returning a positive one causes `a` to be sorted into an index higher than `b`.

`a - b` in a comparator is a shorthand way of writing out that we want to sort in ascending order, because when `a > b` it will return a positive number so that `a` moves up, when `a < b` it returns a negative one so `a` moves down, and when they're the same it returns zero.

(you could also use `b - a` if you want descending)

Answer (score 1):

First we need to assign references to our DOM nodes. We'll call the parent `selectContainer` and its list of children to `selectChildren`.

Next we need a Regular Expression pattern to extract the value of interest that we're using to apply the sorting logic to. In this case we're extracting the digit number in the parenthesized km.

Finally, we cast the children elements to an array so it is iterable, allowing us to use the `sort` method.

Inside our sort method we are using our Regular Expression pattern to extrapolate the number value we care about.

```
const selectContainer = document.querySelector('select');
const selectChildren = selectContainer.querySelectorAll('option');
const pattern = /.*\((\d+)\skm\).*/;

const sorted = [...selectChildren].sort((a, b) => {
  const _a = parseInt(a.innerText.match(pattern)[1]);
  const _b = parseInt(b.innerText.match(pattern)[1]);
  return _a < _b ? -1 : 1;
});

sorted.forEach(child => selectContainer.append(child));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant expect to write a generic function that will know how to compare any string based on any numbers inside of it.  Trying to sort any kind of string this way is that it is very specific to your use case. Here, we have to believe that the number we care about will be inside of parenthesis and followed by km.

Sorting Requires providing a comparison function to your array.sort().   Given this specific use case, I used a regex to pull out the number from your string and then compare numbers.

```js
//input:
var arr = ['A (9 km)', 'B (10 km)', 'C (2 km)'];

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const regEx = /\((\d+)\s{1}km\)/;
  
  const aNumMatch = a.match(regEx);
  const aNum = aNumMatch[1]
  
  const bNumMatch = b.match(regEx);
  const bNum = bNumMatch[1];
  
  return (aNum - bNum);
});

for(let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++){
  console.log(arr[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned, multiple use cases, let's talk about the sorting parts. Once you have a collection of the strings, and the numbers, perhaps something in the form tuple, like so:

```
var pairs = [
  [9, 'A (9 km)'],
  [5, 'B (5 km)'],
  [5, 'C (5 km)']
];
```

You can tackle the problem in any number of ways, let's start with a few simple
built in array functions, such as [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Sort, is an array function which takes a "comparator" function, which you design, to sort an array.

Here is a simple example of the "comparator" function, assuming you have a collection of tuples, as I outlined above:

```
function compareDistanceTuples(a, b) {
    // is A less than B?
    if (a[0] < b[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
    // is A grater than B?
    if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        return 1;
    }
    // A must be equal to B
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), along with your new "comparator" to generate your
sorted list, like so:

```
var sorted = pairs.sort(compareDistanceTuples).map(function(tuple){
     return tuple[1];
});
```